# CoordinatorTabLayout without collapse functionality

Tags: android, layout, view

Im searching for a specific Layout which I couldnt find in the internet. It somehow looks like a [CoordinatorTabLayout](https://github.com/hugeterry/CoordinatorTabLayout) but without collapsing while scrolling down/up. I founded this View in the App "BlackMusicPlayer" which looks like this:
[image]
[image]

When youre going to tap on the Picture the View is expanding. Should I create a new Layout from scratch or is there anything out there I could youse? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can get reference of appBarLayout and try this

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
p.setScrollFlags(0);
toolbar.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Use coordinator layout with collapsing toolbar , and this will keep the collapsing toolbar always expanded

Answer (score 0):

> CoordinatorTabLayout is a custom composite control that quickly implements the combination of TabLayout and CoordinatorLayout.

may [this github sample](https://github.com/hugeterry/CoordinatorTabLayout) helps you